Stationary distribution of $M/M/\infty$ queue
Looking in Wikipedia and other sources, I've found that the stationary distribution of an M/M/$\infty$ queue is given by
$$
\pi(x) = \left(\frac{\lambda}{\mu}\right)^x \frac{e^{-\lambda/\mu}}{x!} \quad (\forall x \geq 0).
$$
I want to compute this from scratch, but without using the so-called "balance equations" or the "transition rate matrix": this is because my competences in computing a stationary distribution rely only on knowing that the stationary distribution is an invariant measure, so $\pi = P\pi$, where $P$ is the transition stochastic matrix (the entries of each row sum up to 1, I read that the entries of a transition rate matrix sum up to 0 instead).
So, consider
$$
p_{x,x+1} = \frac{\lambda}{\lambda + x\mu} \quad \text{and} \quad p_{x,x-1} = \frac{x\mu}{\lambda + x\mu},
$$
as entries of $P$ for all $x \geq 1$, and $p_{0,1} = 1$.
Then we use the invariant property $\pi(y)=\sum_{x\ge0}\pi(x)p_{x,y}$. An easy computation for the firsts values $0,1,2,3$ gives $$\pi(0)=\pi(1)\frac\mu{\lambda+\mu}\Rightarrow\pi(1)=\pi(0)\Big(1+\frac\lambda\mu\Big)\\\pi(2)=\pi(0)\frac\lambda\mu\cdot\frac{\lambda+2\mu}{2\mu}\\\pi(3)=\pi(0)\frac{\lambda^3+3\lambda^2\mu}{2\cdot3\mu^3},$$
so we deduce that for every $x\ge1$, $$\pi(x)=\pi(0)\bigg(\frac{\lambda^x}{x!\mu^x}+\frac{\lambda^{x-1}}{(x-1)!\mu^{x-1}}\bigg).$$ Now, we know that it must hold that $\sum_{x\ge0}\pi(x)=1$: in the above expression, the terms in brackets each go to $e^{\lambda/\mu}$, so we deduce that $\pi(0)=\frac12e^{-\lambda/\mu}$. Hence, in the ned we get $$\pi(x)=\bigg(\frac\lambda\mu\bigg)^{x-1}\frac{e^{-\lambda/\mu}}{2(x-1)!}\bigg(\frac\lambda{\mu x}+1\bigg),$$ which is quite different from what we have above.
Did I mess up in the computation or is something else the problem? (Maybe it is right this way?)

You have the wrong transition matrix for a continuous-time Markov chain on discrete state space. If you are dead set on using a transition matrix then you need to take $P=\exp(tQ)$ for some $t>0$, where $Q$ is the rate matrix of the chain.
Then observe that $P\pi = \pi$ is equivalent to $Q\pi = 0$, and the latter gives you exactly the balance equations.

Do the transition probabilities remain as I wrote them ($p_{x,x+1}$ and $p_{x,x-1}$)? For me it is important that they stay this way, as I am following an example in a paper and they are defined this way, but give straight away the stationary distribution.

No. Your transition probabilities are those of the discrete-time Markov chain consisting of the jumps of the original continuous-time chain, also known as its jump chain. These two do not necessarily have the same stationary distribution.
